# Pylons howto get windows user

Tags: windows, pylons

Is it possible to get the current windows user from with in pylons?

I am starting a pylons app that is going to be used from within a controlled Windows domain.

Is it possible to get the logged on user?

Much like I would do in ASP.NET with Page.User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the standard [getpass](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module:

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
```